# How to get value from PHP Object

Tags: php

I have an object `$post_object`. I want to get the `ID` from it. How will I achieve it? I treated it as array but my page stuck and I'm unable to see the value. This is my object.

```
WP_Post Object
(
    [ID] => 457
    [post_author] => 1
    [post_date] => 2015-12-14 06:40:12
    [post_date_gmt] => 2015-12-14 06:40:12
    [post_content] => 
    [post_title] => The Biggie
    [post_excerpt] => 
    [post_status] => publish
    [comment_status] => closed
    [ping_status] => closed
    [post_password] => 
    [post_name] => the-biggie
    [to_ping] => 
    [pinged] => 
    [post_modified] => 2015-12-14 06:40:12
    [post_modified_gmt] => 2015-12-14 06:40:12
    [post_content_filtered] => 
    [post_parent] => 0
    [guid] => http://socialcize.com/new/?post_type=sm_points_templates&p=457
    [menu_order] => 0
    [post_type] => sm_points_templates
    [post_mime_type] => 
    [comment_count] => 0
    [filter] => raw
)
```

I just want to return the `ID`, value 457 from it.

Thank-you in advance.

Comment: OMG thankyou so much. It worked.

Comment: echo $examplePost->ID; // Display the post's ID